# how can i update my dynamic ip with curl php

Tags: php

i have registered a domain and now i want to host it on my own home server ...

i want to setup a system with php curl so that i login to my domain website and update my name servers i.e

http://mycompany.com/webhosting/domain/manage.php?action=showNS&domain_id=10003489

i want to login to that site and auto update my dynamic ip address...

Comment: (From the description, it sounds like you are trying to setup a dynamic DNS updater for your system; if so...) Most consumer routers support dynamic DNS directly, and for those that don't, there are plenty of desktop and server apps, across OSs, that achieve the same effect. Do you _really_ want to write code to fix this?

Comment: ofcourse i want to write code to fix that wth php curl

Comment: How does the site handle authentication ? Care to show us the ip-changing form ?

Comment: @testkhan: does the site ask for some sort of user/password ? Do you have to speak `friend` to enter ? After you *do* enter, how would you change your IP as a regular user ? Is there a form with text inputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an easier time using DynDns.com or No-Ip.com. They offer free software that will likely run on your home server and update your free hostname (yourserver.no-ip.info, or whatever).

From there, just set your domain to use a CNAME and point it to your dynamic DNS hostname. Your domain will always be up-to-date with your current IP and you won't have to worry about nasty web scraping with PHP and CURL.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel and Marcelo are both correct: Rather than writing a script to log in and update your settings with your DNS provider via web scraping, you can simply assign 'www.yourdomain.com' as a CNAME to a free Dynamic DNS hostname with DynDNS.com or No-IP. Both companies offer update client software which synchronize your hostname with your IP address whenever a change occurs, and if you're really interested in writing the script yourself, our update API is open:

https://www.dyndns.com/developers/

You can also find update clients in most Linksys, D-Link and Netgear routers, though software clients are usually more reliable and easier to troubleshoot. We also offer a paid service if you'd prefer to eschew the 'myhostname.dyndns.org' and update your domain directly.